# Mouse clicks stop registering in some or all windows

Tags: usb, mouse

I've been running Ubuntu for years without problems, using mostly the same hardware for much of that time.  But recently, I've begun having a strange problem, and I'm not sure where it might be coming from.

The mouse clicks stop registering in all the inactive windows.

I'm running Gnome classic/fallback, with Gnome panel and Cairo dock, and compiz.

Sometimes the problem happens after a day or two, sometimes immediately upon a reboot. If I'm using Firefox, it works fine, although I can no longer move or close the window with the mouse. New windows are simply dead.  If it happens on boot, Cairo dock will work, but no windows.  By work, I mean the mouse clicks; keyboard works normally.

I've tried resetting Compiz and gnome-panel, which don't help.  What does work, and is the best workaround so far, is to bring up a virtual terminal, then switch back to the GUI using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>.  Then everything works fine.

I've tried connecting a different mouse, to no avail (both USB, but I doubt that matters).

I've seem others that seem to have the same problem, back as far as 12.xx, but no answers.  Seems like some have the problem with xfce, etc.  One person seemed to fix it by updating his system, but I tried that and it didn't help.

I'm really not sure in what system this problem originates.  The only clue I have that's new is the switching to VT and back.  Whatever is run when switching back must reset the offending system.

### Edit (1)

I was able to determine that this problem is also exhibited when booting and logging in to the guest session, running Unity.

I don't know if I have any PS/2 mice hidden away somewhere, but I'll check.  However, both the keyboard and mouse are plugged into the same USB port, and the keyboard works fine.  Also, another USB mouse is plugged into a different USB port, and has the same problem.  One mouse is Logitech, and one is IBM, and I've never had problems with either.

### Edit (2)

Today, the problem arose while using the system.  I connected another mouse to a different port, which also didn't work.  Then, I disconnected the first mouse and keyboard from the old USB-1 hub, which was connected via an old USB-1 cable, and connected it directly to a USB port on the front of the system.  Problem went away.

So, I am now running without the extension cable, but with the hub, to see if the hub itself is OK.  If the problem recurs, I may try it with a USB-2 hub, just to see if perhaps USB-1 might be a problem.  But nothing has changed that recently except software, so maybe it's something in the kernel.

*One other thing about the problem...* There is usually one working window where the mouse works - usually firefox, but I use that a lot, so it's hard to tell for sure.  When I open another window on top of this working window, and try to click or highlight something, the underlying window receives the mouse clicks, and its text will become highlighted just like the top window isn't there.  But the top window does receive the keyboard events.  So, it's puzzling to me how the hub would cause this, but I'm a mere mortal.

Comment: Does this also happen in the guest session?

Comment: I had what sound like similar issues, which went away when I plugged in a PS2 mouse. Other USB mice had the same issue. At the time, I could not find any reported bugs with USB mice.

Comment: @Fabby: Good question, and one I considered.  But it's not repeatable in a way that's easy to test, and I don't want to use the guest session for possibly several days.

Comment: @CarlH:  Thanks for that input.  Although I don't really want to switch to a PS2 mouse, it does suggest a possible area to investigate.  I'll see if I have an old mouse for testing.

Comment: @MartyFried: I can imagine...  The guest session would rule out a hardware problem if it didn't happen there, so that's why I asked...

Comment: @Fabby:  Well, it seems that the problem is more consistent than it seemed; when I started up today from power off, I had the problem, so I repeated, but logged in as guest, and it still had the problem (using Unity instead of Gnome fallback).

Comment: So it's definitely not a mouse hardware problem, not a profile problem, so a system problem or USB bus HW problem:  what happens if you re-load the modules for the mouse?  If that doesn't help: reload the USB modules and report back. If you don't have a PS/2 mouse hidden away, maybe you've got one of these USB-PS/2 dongles they used to give for free with every mouse?  You look "experienced" enough to have one of those in a box in the basement!  **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby:  Thanks for the input... I can't find any PS/2 adapters or mice. But I discovered something new today: the mouse and KB were plugged into an old passive USB hub, via an old USB-1 extension cable. I switched the mouse to a direct USB port, and it started working. I'm adding more detail to my question... –  Marty Fried 11 mins ago

Comment: @CarlH:  I added more information, in case it might apply to your issues, assuming you still have them.  Perhaps it would help if you want to stop using a PS/2 mouse.

Comment: @MartyFried: I'm not a god neither, just a Vorlon!  ;-)  It's unclear to me from your description if the problem *exists* (or not) without the USB hub as well.

Comment: @Fabby: Well, so far, after only one reboot, and less than a day, the problem has not come up using the USB hub without the small extension cable, in the same port.  So, I can't yet say it's solved, or if it is, why it's so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's been several days since I removed a short USB cable extension I had connected from the computer's USB-2 port to the cable from the old passive USB hub, and through several reboots and suspends, I've had no more problems

I hope this might be helpful for others, as I've seen a bunch of very similar, or even duplicate, situations both here and elsewhere.  Mostly, they were older topics, and although I tried posting to get more information, I got no response.

I'm tempted to wait a while longer before accepting this as the final solution, but I'm afraid I'll forget, so I'll close it now.